# Retrieving pen pressure with Python 2.7 via PySide

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside

I'm using Python 2.7 with PySide and want to use [this](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTabletEvent.html#PySide.QtGui.QTabletEvent) to retrieve pen pressure from my wacom pen.

So I tried setting up the following

```
import PySide
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
pressure = PySide.QtGui.QTabletEvent.pressure()
print pressure
```

That threw the following error

```
pressure = PySide.QtGui.QTabletEvent.pressure()
TypeError: descriptor 'pressure' of 'PySide.QtGui.QTabletEvent' object needs an argument
```

The object it needs is a "PySide.QtGui.QTabletEvent" Object. But I have no idea how can I retrieve such an object.

So my question is, how do I retrieve the wacom penpressure using QTabletEvent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to receive the actual event and obtain the `pressure` from it.

Example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def tabletEvent(self, e):
        print(e.pressure())

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Ohh, i see. How could i do this without having to do the app.exec_(), takes quite a long time to run and would love to have it in the background in my 3D program.

Comment: @user1095570 Unfortunately I think there is no way to do it. Only widgets can receive these events.